# "show" was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, class

I am getting error "show was not declared in this scope " while compiling below program even after declaring and defining. Don't know where i am wrong. Please suggest.

Thanks

```
 #include < iostream >

using namespace std;

class add

{

        int x;
        int y;

        public:
                void putdata(int,int);
                void show(add);
                friend add sum(add,add);
};

void add :: putdata (int m,int n)

{

        x = m;
        y = n;
}

void add :: show(add c)

{

        cout<<c.x <<" "<<c.y<<endl;
}

add sum(add a1,add a2)

{

        add a3;
        a3.x = a1.x + a2.x;
        a3.y = a1.y + a2.y;
        return(a3);
}


int main()
{

        add p,q,r;

        p.putdata(10,15);
        r.putdata(20,25);

        r = sum(p,q);

        show(r);

        return 0;
}
```

~

Comment: Please fix your formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`show` is a non-static member function of `add`, so you need to call it on an instance of `add`:

```
p.show(r);
```

It doesn't make much sense like this, so you can either make it a non-member function, or remove its parameter:

```
show(r); // non-member
```

or

```
r.show(); // member
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the show(r) member function from within an object of add, just like,
r.show(r);